# Restrict API access directly with static IP in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-appservice

I've used IP restrictions to great success. APIM is given a static IP, so you can setup an IP restriction in the "root API" that allows only the APIM calls. This results in a 403 if you call the root API directly.

but now when I'm Calling api with front end url also getting 403 how to resolve 403 issue i have give permision in APIM in Inbound Aud but still getting 403 with the front end api url.

Answer (score 1):

zubairz, if you need to go the single IP route, I would recommend trying to capture what IP's are being sent if possible. Make use of the logging features to try and capture the IPs that are actually being used as it sounds like a request might be coming from a VNET or another IP that you're not anticipating.

Have you considered using service tags instead? This would be a recommended approach as it creates the allow/deny based on a product/region level rather than a single IP address. You could add an APIM service tag to your web app and then More information on service tags can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview). More information on Service tags in Azure Web Apps can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#set-a-service-tag-based-rule).